# Get n highest y values from list of coordinate pairs in Python 3

Tags: python, list

I'm aware of how to get the n highest values in a list but I want a quick function that gets the highest y values of a coordinate pair.

I know the following gives the n highest values in a list

```
[a[i] for i in np.argsort(a)[-n:]]
```

But what I really want is to feed it coordinates of the form

```
[[1,2], [3,4], [6,2], [6,11], [1,5]]
```

and get n coordinates with the highest y values from it, i.e. for n = 2

```
[[6,11], [1,5]]
```

But I can't quite get past the last step. Not having to use external libraries other than numpy would be a bonus. I tried changing the axis of argsort(list, axis=0) but that didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `sorted` function takes named argument `key` which is used to compute a compare key for each value.

```
>>> sorted([[1,2], [3,4], [6,2], [6,11], [1,5]], key=lambda pair: pair[1])[-n:]
[[1, 5], [6, 11]]
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, terser, answer you could use `nlargest` from `heapq`

```
nlargest(n, your2DList, key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

Comment: This also has the advantage of being faster for `n` much smaller than `len(your2Dlist)`.

Comment: from the help: `   nlargest(n, iterable, key=None)
        Find the n largest elements in a dataset.
        
        Equivalent to:  sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=True)[:n]`. Is that faster? Anyway, that's the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

just sort the list using 2nd coord as key, and print the 2 last items:

```
z = [[1,2], [3,4], [6,2], [6,11], [1,5]]

print(sorted(z,key=lambda x:x[1])[-2:])
```

result:

```
[[1, 5], [6, 11]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one NumPy based approach with [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) -

```
n = 2 # Number of entries to keep
arr = np.asarray(input_list) # Convert to array for further processing
out = arr[arr[:,1].argsort()[-n:]].tolist()
```

Another NumPy based one and should be faster with [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) -

```
out = arr[(-arr[:,1]).argpartition(n,axis=0)[:n]].tolist()
```